# How to substract 2 queries with multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to substract the results for each prod_id in this 2 queries.

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name, SUM(quantity) 
FROM purchasesdetails 
LEFT JOIN products ON (products._id=purchasesdetails.prod_id) 
GROUP BY prod_id
```

Minus

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name, SUM(quantity) 
FROM notedetails 
LEFT JOIN products 
ON(notedetails.prod_id=products._id) 
GROUP BY prod_id
```

So the final result is

```
|prod_name|SUM1-SUM2|
```

prod_name is in the products table.

This is the output of the first query

```
prod_id | prod_name   | SUM(quantity)
176     | ANTIPIRINA  | 21
177     | BOMBAY      | 22
```

This is the output of the second query

```
prod_id | prod_name   | SUM(quantity)
176     | ANTIPIRINA  | 10
177     | BOMBAY      | 15
```

This is the desired output

```
prod_id | prod_name   | sum1-sum2
176     | ANTIPIRINA  | 11
177     | BOMBAY      | 7
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show some sample data and desired result please.

Comment: I want to make the operation for each row (product)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name, SUM(quantity) 
FROM purchasesdetails 
LEFT JOIN products ON (products._id=purchasesdetails.prod_id) 
GROUP BY prod_id where prod_in not in SELECT prod_id 
FROM notedetails 
LEFT JOIN products 
ON(notedetails.prod_id=products._id) 
GROUP BY prod_id
```

U can use not in clause.

Comment: I want to make the operation for each row (product)

Comment: This operation does what you ask for - it performs the calculation on each row where prod_id are matched in the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

For this two subquery, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    T1.prod_id, T1.prod_name, SUM(T1.quantity) AS `sum1-sum2`
FROM (
    SELECT prod_id, prod_name, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
    FROM purchasesdetails 
    LEFT JOIN products ON (products._id=purchasesdetails.prod_id) 
    GROUP BY prod_id
    UNION
    SELECT prod_id, prod_name, 0 - SUM(quantity) AS quantity
    FROM notedetails 
    LEFT JOIN products 
    ON(notedetails.prod_id=products._id) 
    GROUP BY prod_id
) T1
GROUP BY T1.prod_id, T1.prod_name
```

If your table `products` is main table, you also can do it like this:

```
SELECT n.prod_id, n.prod_name, SUM(p.quantity - n.quantity) AS quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN notedetails n
ON products._id = n.prod_id
LEFT JOIN purchasesdetails p
ON p.prod_id = products._id
GROUP BY products._id
```